# How can I add books to users and users to books?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have two entities, Users and Books with a has_and_belongs_to_many relationship. How can I have a button in the Book#Show view that when clicked adds the user to Book.user_ids[] and the book to User.book_ids[]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First,  stop using  has_and_belongs_to_many. Use has_many :through.  Much better if and when you want an attribute on the join table.

Second, I would add have a controller like this.

```
/books/:id
```

routes would look like:

```
namespace :assignments do
  resources  :books, :only => [:show] do
    resources  :users, :only => [:update]
  end
end
```

then the show action would be:

```
# /books/1
def show
  @book = Book.find(params[:id])
  @users = User.all # All is probably not what you want
end
```

the update_action would be in the /users_controller.rb

```
def update
  @book = Book.find(params[:book_id])
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @book.add_user(@user)
end
```

Now in models/book.rb

```
def add_user(@user)
  #  this is one of many things you could do...  This is not the best performance
  @book.user_ids = @book.user_ids << @user.id
  @book.save
end
```

Finally in the view:

```
 <% @users.each do |user| %>
   <%= link_to "Add #{user.name}", assignments_book_user_path(@book, user), :method => 'PUT' %>
 <% end %>
```